# Script tag in view containing document.ready function is not getting hit after adding document.ready in layout page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$().ready(function () {
    #debugger;
    $('#myTable').DataTable();

    $('#myTable1').DataTable();
});
</script>
```

The above is the script in view

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$sidebar = $('.sidebar');
$sidebar_img_container = $sidebar.find('.sidebar-background');
$full_page = $('.full-page');
$sidebar_responsive = $('body > .navbar-collapse');
 window_width = $(window).width();
</script>
```

The above is the script part in layout.
When i add the script tag in layout the one in my view pages are not getting hit.

Comment: Note that `#debugger` will result in a `SyntaxError`. Javascript comments use `//` or `/* */`

Comment: @CertainPerformance even if remove the debugger the part in script tag is not getting called,while other pages with different layout having no script tag work just fine.

Comment: If you want to use `debugger`, you should take out the `#` before it - if you want to comment it out, use `//` instead of `#`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am able to use debugger in other pages by the same way(#debugger)

Comment: How do you know it is not getting hit ? Can you put a `console.log(123);` inside that and confirm whether it is being printed to your browser console. Also look for script errors in browser console.

Comment: @Shyju for that purpose i have put a debugger which doesn’t get hit.

Comment: and there are no script errors

Comment: Make sure there's no typo on the script (I spotted missing closing brace `}` in the second script tag). Can you provide a fiddle to demonstrate what doesn't work, since this problem related to JS and jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$sidebar = $('.sidebar');
$sidebar_img_container = $sidebar.find('.sidebar-background');
$full_page = $('.full-page');
$sidebar_responsive = $('body > .navbar-collapse');
window_width = $(window).width();
</script>
```

in this code i can't see the curely brace getting closed.obviously its not gonna work

Comment: I have just put a part of the code,in actual script it is present,it is a 2 page code of js.